# What is the difference between Href and Url.Content?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Both `Href` and `Url.Content` can be used to resolve a virtual path, which is relative to the virtual root path ~, of files or folders.

What is the difference between Href and Url.Content ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're quite similar, though `Href` comes from the ASP.NET WebPages stack. In an MVC context you should use `Url.Content`.

Answer (score 14):

url.content does alot more than just creating an normal href, it takes into context the application's sub/virtual directory, whereas href it's a straight pointer.

for best practice use url.content, this way you know that if your site moves into a sub/virtual directory, your link will still work.

Comment: Can you give me an example in which they do different results?

Comment: +1 Thanks, I used Href because it's shorter and more to the point but it won't work with Virtual Directories indeed. Using Url.Content now.

Answer (score 3):

Href is part of System.Web.WebPages and Url.Content is part of System.Mvc. I think that if you have an MVC app, you'll get both, but some other usages (like webforms) will only have Href available to them.