# Should I use @Url.Content, @Href, or just ~

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Should I use

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Styles/style.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
```

or

```
<link href="@Href("~/Styles/style.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
```

or

```
<link href="~/Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

for referencing StyleSheets, JavaScripts and images?

Is there any difference between above three?

Comment: First off, are you referencing this `style.css` on all pages or just specific ones?

Comment: This is just an example, could be any css, js or img.

Comment: How would the href get resolved in your third example?  As for the other two, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883192/what-is-the-difference-between-href-and-url-content

Comment: All three convert to the same working file.

Comment: Well, if you're planning on referencing this style sheet on every page, I would put this in your bundle.config file.. but @stephen.vakil posted the similar question.. I prefer to use Url.Content

Comment: Reading this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896725/108448) `@Url.Content` seems to be a better solution then `@Href`. But that still leaves the `~` solution, what is the cons/pros of using that?